# Mongomapper uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongomapper

I have user model

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document


  key :phone, Integer, :required => true, :unique => true
  key :is_confirmed, Boolean, :default => false
  timestamps!
end
```

and validate uniqueness of phone but i can create user with the same phone without error.WHY?

why validate uniqueness doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**MongoMapper** uses [ActiveModel:Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html), so it works almost exactly like [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html)

Try this to validate: [**validates_uniqueness_of**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

```
validates_uniqueness_of :phone
```

Validations are run when attempting to save a record. If validations `fail`, save will return `false`.

Most **Simple Validations** can be declared along with the **keys**.

Example:

```
class Person
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :first_name,  String,   :required => true
  key :last_name,   String,   :required => true
  key :age,         Integer,  :numeric => true
  key :born_at,     Time
  key :active,      Boolean
  key :fav_colors,  Array
end
```

The available options when defining `keys` are:

- **:required** – Boolean that declares validate_presence_of
- **:unique** – Boolean that declares validates_uniqueness_of
- **:numeric** – Boolean that declares validates_numericality_of
- **:format** – Regexp that is passed to validates_format_of
- **:in** – Array that is passed to validates_inclusion_of
- **:not_in** – Array that is passed to validates_exclusion_of
- **:length** – Integer, Range, or Hash that is passed to validates_length_of